# Computer Restarts after pressing "Install Ubuntu"/"Try Ubuntu without Installing" Option

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, restart

I am trying to dual boot my laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10.
But, when I press "install ubuntu " or "try Ubuntu without installing" option on my laptop, from a live Usb, the Ubuntu loading screen with those dots pops up, and suddenly the system restarts, not even entering the setup.

My laptop:
Dell Inspiron 3543
Processor: Inter Core i5 5th gen
GPU: Nvidia 820m
Current OS: Windows 10
8gb Ram

Comment: Try disabling secure boot from BIOS sittings. Let me know if that works ;-)

Comment: Also, make sure the usb-drive you are using is not damaged, or that you wrote the the image to it correctly :-)